# Help identifying a plant

Tags: identification

I was walking home and spotted this really pretty bush. Would anyone possibly know what kind of flowers these are?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: It is Oleander as described, botanical name Nerium oleander - sap is toxic, but as long as you don't ingest it (wear gloves or wash hands if you need to handle it) it's fine, it won't kill you

Comment: @Cakelady, it's great that you included pictures. That really helps. It would also help if you told us the general area you lived and whether it's growing wild or if it looks like someone planted it. If it's native to your state, that really narrows it down. Growing zones would also narrow down the type.

Comment: @Dalton you're welcome. I tried to get a really good picture. The general area I live in is kind of a semi desert I believe, I'm not sure if I answered that correctly. The plant was growing against a wall near a few homes. It came past it and it was really beautiful.

Answer (score 9):

It's an oleander. Beautiful but **all** parts are highly toxic. Supposedly one of the most poisonous garden ornamentals... but there are many.

Most oleanders are very fragrant but not all. Winters where I live, though fairly mild, are still too cold for growing them. In warmer subtropical regions, they're often planted along streets and in parks.

Notice how the inner part of the flowers of this oleander from Wikipedia is similar to the one you show?

[image: Oleander flowers]

Comment: Happy to help. :)